# Unable to Update User Data Using Function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

In my Angular Project, I'm trying to have a sign in function that signs the user in with google and then updates their user data dependent on whether or not they already have the `approved` role.

When trying to make this work, neither of my `console.log` statements fire so I'm not sure what I can be doing to get into those blocks.

```js
async handleSignIn() {
    const credential = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.default.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
    return this.manageUserData(credential.user)
}

private async manageUserData(user: User) {
    let data$; // Init Variable
    let update$; // Init Variable
    const userCollection = this.afs.collection<User[]>('users'); // Sets Path for Data
     console.log(user.uid);
    data$ = userCollection.doc<User>(user.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe( // Fetches Document
        map(action => { // Maps To Be Able To Do Things
            const payload = action.payload.data(); // Sets Payload Data as the main `payload` variable
            console.log("In place", payload)
            if(payload.roles.approved == true || false) {
                console.log("main block")
                update$ = {
                    uid: user.uid,
                    email: user.email,
                    displayName: user.displayName,
                    photoURL: user.photoURL
                }
            } else {
                console.log("else block")
                update$ = {
                    uid: user.uid,
                    email: user.email,
                    displayName: user.displayName,
                    photoURL: user.photoURL,
                    roles: {
                        approved: false
                    }
                }
            }
            const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
            return userRef.set(update$, { merge: true });
        })
    )
}
```

The `console.log(user.uid)` statement returns my firebase UID: `rKlGL943eqfaPVWLh2EEUVBoOvg2`

Edit: I also tried using the ternary operator here and organizing functions better:

```
function hasApprovedStatus() {
      update$ = {
        uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        photoURL: user.photoURL
      }
      userRef.set(update$, { merge: true });
    }
    function hasNoApprovedStatus() {
      update$ = {
        uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        photoURL: user.photoURL,
        roles: {
          approved: false
        }
      }
      userRef.set(update$, { merge: true })
    }
data$ = userCollection.doc<User>(user.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe( // Fetches Document
      map(action => action.payload.data().roles.approved ? hasApprovedStatus() : hasNoApprovedStatus())
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(user.uid)` right before you use it, and include the updated code and its output in your question? Please also include a screenshot of the document that you are trying to load for this user.

Comment: The document I'm trying to load doesn't exist, so what I'm trying to detect is if it doesn't exist, go into the else block and set that path to it, and if it does exist, then leave the `roles` part of it.

Comment: I'll do the console.log and update the post though.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Edit has been made

Comment: Wouldn't the `map(action => ` only be invoked if there **is** a document in the result? Since you don't have a matching document, I'm not sure it'll run. The easiest way to check that is to see if the `console.log("In place", payload)` is showing in the output.

Comment: Right, which it doesn't. So how would I go about running something different if the document doesn't exist (eg. if the `map(action =>...` doesn't run, is there an operator I can use for that and just move the `else` part of my if block to that?

Comment: Also tried something else, which didn't work either.

Comment: The [documentation for AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) seems to check the length of the result: `<div *ngIf="items.length === 0">No results, try clearing filters</div>`. I'm not sure how that applies to your code though.

Comment: Yeah I don't know if that applies here as I'm not really filtering- I'm just seeing if a certain content exists.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that later. I'm not sure what type you get from `snapshotChanges()` in that case, but it might be worth checking if it has anything like an `exists` or `length`.

Comment: I'll look into it but it isn't just if the whole document exists, it is if a specific piece of data within it exists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that your async method `manageUserData()` is not actually `return`ing anything.

The method is creating an Observable from `userCollection.doc<User>(user.uid).snapshotChanges()` and assigning it to local var `data$` but it's not returning that from the method, and it's also not subscribing to it. So you appear to be creating an Observable that never gets subscribed to, and therefore your `map` function will never be invoked.

What you need to do is `return` the Observable you're creating (also, no need to assign it to a local var unless you're going to use that var for something):

```js
return userCollection.doc<User>(user.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(...
```

That will cause `manageUserData()` to return a Promise (since it's `async`) that resolves to an Observable.

Since `handleSignIn()` returns the return value of `manageUserData()`, that Promise will be passed along to whoever calls `handleSignIn()`. That calling method would look something like this:

```js
async signIn() {
  const handle: Observable<any> = await this.handleSignIn();

  handle.subscribe();
}
```

Since `handleSignIn()` returns a Promise, we must `await` that Promise's resolution and then subscribe to the resulting Observable (i.e., your `snapshotChanges()`).

Unless you need this to be Promise-based, you might consider simply returning the Observable from `manageUserData()` and `handleSignIn()` instead of wrapping it in a Promise (by making those methods `async`), then you wouldn't need the extra step of `await`ing the Promise to resolve.

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-function-return-observable?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) with a mocked version of this chain of method calls working correctly.

**Update in response to Comments, 12/29/2020:**

If you need to filter your stream so that the first line in your `map` function, `const payload = action.payload.data()`, will always retrieve a value from method call `action.payload.data()`, you can add a [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) operator into your pipe before the `map`:

```js
return userCollection.doc<User>(user.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  filter(action => Boolean(action.payload?.data?.())),
  map(action => { ... )
)
```

A couple other observations:

1. The first line in your `map` function is

```js
const payload = action.payload.data();
```

in which you're invoking the `data()` method on the `payload` property. Is `data()` truly a method or is it just a property?

2. The third line in your `map` function is

```js
if(payload.roles.approved == true || false) { ...
```

That's a strangely constructed condition. What condition(s) are you testing for?

The  `|| false` essentially does nothing because it's only evaluated if `payload.roles.approved == true` is `false`, so you'd just be checking `if (false || false)`, which doesn't seem very useful.

If your intention was to check if `payload.roles.approved` is either strictly `true` or strictly `false`, then you would do this (note that I'm using strict equality, `===`, rather than loose equality because that's preferred unless there's a good reason to use loose equality):

```js
if(payload.roles.approved === true || payload.roles.approved === false) { ...
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with that is when I do the `handle.subscribe();` it only outputs the `In place undefined` (the "In place` comes from the string part of that, and it says that the payload is == undefined). And then I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined`. So while this helps me get into that pipe, it doesn't get me into the if or else block, which is where I need to be at.

Comment: That's because the observable stream is not emitting what you are expecting it to. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined` means that your payload on the action is undefined. Perhaps not all actions will have a payload? In that case, add a `filter(action => !!action.payload)` to your stream. This will prevent any actions (values) in the stream from emitting if there is no payload property on them.

Comment: Where should that be added exactly? I tried adding it to this statement: `map(action => {...` and it gave me a bunch of errors so I don't think I did it in the right spot. @Jusmpty